# Open webview in separate browser on each click?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am preparing sample app based on Web View. In my Splash screen have to load on url,if i click on splash screen it will open another site.It is working fine.But when i click on splash screen i want open separate browser.For that i have used following code,

```
 this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
              view.loadUrl(url);
              return true;
            }
        });
```

But it is opening same browser.Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`view.loadUrl(url)` will open the url in the same WebView. You have to define rule when to load in the same WebView or another seperate WebView or Browser. To load in seperate webview call `anotherWebView.loadUrl(url)`. Or browser call with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.

The workaround could be like this-

```
if(need to load same webView)
{
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
else if(need to load same webView)
{
    anotherWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
else
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: suppose i want open n number of web browsers....that time need to prepare n webviews...

Comment: Can you please distinguish between web browser & webviews.